[Angular 18]Error: Could not find column with id "complete"
I am trying to follow through the book intitled "Pro Angular 16" and again, I am stuck early as the chapter 2 due to the following error, thrown by the TypeScript compiler embedded in Angular 18 developpment tools:
Error: Could not find column with id "complete".
The similar questions and answers associated allowed me not to resolve the problem so I am trying my luck here.
app.component.ts
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { TodoList } from "./todoList";
import { TodoItem } from "./todoItem";
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { MatButtonModule } from '@angular/material/button';
import { MatToolbarModule } from '@angular/material/toolbar';
import { MatIconModule } from '@angular/material/icon';
import { MatBadgeModule } from '@angular/material/badge';
import { MatTableModule } from '@angular/material/table';
import { MatCheckboxModule } from '@angular/material/checkbox';
import { MatFormFieldModule } from '@angular/material/form-field';
import { MatInputModule } from '@angular/material/input';
import { MatSlideToggleModule } from '@angular/material/slide-toggle';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [
    FormsModule,
    MatButtonModule, MatToolbarModule, MatIconModule, MatBadgeModule,
    MatTableModule, MatCheckboxModule, MatFormFieldModule, MatInputModule, MatSlideToggleModule ],
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrl: './app.component.css'
})


export class AppComponent {
  title = 'todo';
  private list = new TodoList('Aurèle', [
    new TodoItem("Finish the UBC website", true),
    new TodoItem('Write some unit tests'),
    new TodoItem('Learn Angular'),
    new TodoItem('Write a word document for the jury'),
    new TodoItem('Buy INCOSE book related to SysML v2', true),
  ]);

  get username(): string {
    return this.list.user;
  }

  get itemCount(): number {
    return this.list.items.filter(item => !item.complete).length;
  }

  get items(): readonly TodoItem[] {
    return this.list.items;
  }
}

app.component.html
<div class="tableContainer">
   <table mat-table [dataSource]="items" class="mat-elevation-z3 fullWidth">
      <ng-container matColumnDef="id">
         <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>#</th>
         <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let i = index">{{ i + 1 }}</td>
      </ng-container>
      
      <ng-container matColumnDef="task">
         <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Task</th>
         <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let item">{{ item.task }}</td>
      </ng-container>
      
      <ng-container matColumDef="complete">
         <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Done</th>
         <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let item">{{ item.complete }}</th>
      </ng-container>

      <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="['id', 'task', 'complete']"></tr>
      <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: ['id', 'task', 'complete'];"></tr>
   </table>
</div>

todoItem.ts
export class TodoItem {
  constructor(public task: string, public complete: boolean = false) {
  }
}

todoList.ts
import { TodoItem } from "./todoItem";

export class TodoList {
   constructor(public user: string, private todoItems: TodoItem[] = []) {
   }

   get items(): readonly TodoItem[] {
      return this.todoItems;
   }

   addItem(task: string) {
      this.todoItems.push(new TodoItem(task));
   }
}

The column id does exist, so I am at a loss and have not the knowledge to resolve this blocking by myself.

please share the todoitem and todolist class or interface details

Sorry, missed your comment. Adding the last class of the data model now.

You have a syntax error, instead of td you used th, that was the root cause of the issue.
Before:
  <ng-container matColumDef="complete">
     <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Done</th>
     <th mat-cell *matCellDef="let item">{{ item.complete }}</th>
  </ng-container>

After:
  <ng-container matColumnDef="complete">
     <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Complete</th>
     <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let item">{{ item.complete }}</td>
  </ng-container>

Stackblitz Demo

Well done for having found such a subtlety and thank you.
Unfortunately, it solved not the issue at hand and the Could not find column with id "complete" error persists!

@AurélienPlazzotta please replicate on the stackblitz and share back

Yarn package manager fails after having fetched 869/869 packages due to "too much recursion" error and therefore, cannot run start command. :-/

@AurélienPlazzotta download the stackblitz and run, its working fine for me, sorry

A comparison between your files and mine made me realize that I missed one letter in my template's attribute.
ng-container matColumdef="complete" in stead of ng-container matColumndef="complete"
That is why the "complete" id was never defined and hence, could not be found. Thank your for your time!

The problem you are facing is that your TodoItem object does not have a property named "done".
That is, in your HTML template you stated explicitly that the third column of the table must get populated from a property "done". Please find below the code snippet from your code that is looking for the "done" property:
So, you either add this property in TodoItem class/interface, or remove the mentioned column from your HTML template.

Indeed, I had no such property in my data model. I was using complete as second property of TodoItem class.
I edited accordinly, but it still not resolved the issue. I also edited the main message to reflect the current situation.

It seems that you are missing the property "task" now. according to your html, you need 3 properties (id, task and done). Would you please confirm that you have all of them

I have not any class property nammed id but the compiler error is still related to `Could not find column with id "complete".

According to the following line in your template, you should add a property named id because you are tying to access it in the HTML template


The data model needs not a id because it is populated by the evaluation of each item in the data source thanks to the attribute binding in [dataSource]="items". Besides, addin it will throw a bunch of errors related to Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'number'andExpected 2-3 arguments, but got 1when parsing my componentAppComponent`.
